# How to change tab behaviour in neovim as specified (luasnip+lsp-popup)

Tags: lua, neovim

I have currently set tab to what is suggested by nvim-cmp:

```lua
    
    mapping = {
            -------other mappings --------

        ["<Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
          if cmp.visible() then
            cmp.select_next_item()
          elseif luasnip.expand_or_jumpable() then
            luasnip.expand_or_jump()
          elseif has_words_before() then
            cmp.complete()
          else
            fallback()
          end
        end, { "i", "s" }),
        ["<S-Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
          if cmp.visible() then
            cmp.select_prev_item()
          elseif luasnip.jumpable(-1) then
            luasnip.jump(-1)
          else
            fallback()
          end
        end, { "i", "s" }),

            -------other mappings --------
    }
```

This is sort of behavior I want but there is one problem.
Say I used a snippet which has multiple placeholders, I write in one of them and then exit insert mode and get into command mode. Now I do not change other place holders and want to insert a tab somewhere else in code, but nvim-cmp assumes(or seems to me atleast) that I am in snippet and would want to jump some characters, and tab will do that. But actually I want to insert actual tab character.

Behaviour I want:
A soon as I exit insert mode, it forgets all placeholder positions. Then I will be able to insert tab. According to me if I wanted to complete a snippet I could have done it in insert mode only.

Please hint to solution or provide required configuration.

[image]

I have been able to partially achieve this using (thanks to [shaeinst](https://neovim.discourse.group/u/shaeinst)):

```lua
mapping = {
-------other mappings --------

        ["<Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
          if cmp.visible() then
            cmp.select_next_item()
          elseif luasnip.expand_or_locally_jumpable() then
            luasnip.expand_or_jump()
          --elseif has_words_before() then
            --cmp.complete()
          else
            fallback()
          end
        end, { "i", "s" }),
    }
```

Using this, cursor only jumps to placeholders when I am inside snippet and also once I have covered all placeholders, it does not jump back. But still my requirement is that as soon as I exit insert mode, all the placeholders are neglected, but untill I am in insert mode I would like to even cycle through placeholders.

Comment: Can you provide a GIF for people to better understand the  issue?

Comment: could you find a solution?

Comment: yes, check [this](https://github.com/Aumnescio/dotfiles/blob/a3efe4d1fdbc7592dd0d84f39539a93b7a119e43/nvim/init.lua#L3365-L3378)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but someone could have the same issue and maybe I'll help a poor soul.

Check https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnip/issues/525

In short, you can use

```
luasnip.setup({
    region_check_events = "CursorHold,InsertLeave",
    -- those are for removing deleted snippets, also a common problem
    delete_check_events = "TextChanged,InsertEnter",
})
```

and that should solve your problem.

From L3MON4D3:

> This is just the default-behaviour of luasnip, placeholders are always
> visited in order (including the $0, which is the one you're jumping
> back into) (and that does not depend on cursor-movement), so if a
> snippet is not jumped "through", you'll end up back in it, regardless
> how the cursor moved.
>
> This can be adjusted by passing a few options to `luasnip.setup`:
> `region_check_events` are the auto-events, on which a check if the
> cursor is still inside the active snippet is performed. If it is not,
> the snippet will be jumped "through"/completed/left, so you won't jump
> back into it.

Hope this helps